# helping to build phone number and email filter by RegEx

Tags: php, regex, laravel, filter

I build Chat by Laravel and Vue.js and I want to block the option to send phone number and email in the messages, and I want to try to cover all the options of sending phone number and email.
It's my first time that I work with RegEx, so sorry for the code :)

```
public function filter($message)
{
    $patterns = array(
        "/[^@\s]*at[^@\s]*\.[^@\s]*/",
        "/[^@\s]*AT[^@\s]*\.[^@\s]*/",
        "/[^@\s]* AT [^@\s]*\.[^@\s]*/",
        "/[^@\s]*@[^@\s]*\.[^@\s]*/",
        "/[^@\s]*AT[^@\s]*/",
        "/\d{3,}/",
        "/[^@\s]*Gmail[^@\s]*/",
        "/[^@\s]*gmail[^@\s]*/",
        "/[^@\s]*yahoo[^@\s]*/",
        "/[^@\s]*Yahoo[^@\s]*/",
        "/[^@\s]*google[^@\s]*/",
        "/[^@\s]*GOOGLE[^@\s]*/",
    );
    $replacement = "[removed]";
    foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
        $message = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $message);
    }

    return $message;
}
```

I know it's not cover all the options, but for this I asking here :)

Comment: _“and I want to try to cover all the options”_ - good luck with that … You’re going to need much more than a regex, to catch stuff like “call me under oh three zero zero five […]” :-)

Comment: As I said "try" :) I know it's hard, but I want to try how much I can :)

Comment: Your filter removes `look at this`. Apart of this, you could make your regexes case insensitive to reduce strongly the number of cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
    function validateEmail(email) {
     var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
    }

function validateNumber(number) {
    var pattern = /[1-9]{1}[0-9]{5}/;
    return pattern.test(number);
}
```

Comment: The minimum number length (excluding the country code) is 7 digits. but my code needed 6 digits

Comment: Your function `validateNumber` returns true for `abc123456xyz`, that is not wanted. You don't match `myemail at domain dot com` that **is** wanted